# Autocomplete textbox with xml source not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a web service that returns a list of strings. 
I am trying to feed that as a datasource for my auto suggesttextbox. 
here is what my webservice returns

```
   <ArrayOfString>
   <string>Air Pollutants</string>
   <string>Air Facilities</string>
   <string>Air Emissions</string>
   <string>Air Pollution</string>
   <string>Air Quality Monitoring</string>
   <string>Air Piracy</string>
  </ArrayOfString>
```

this is my jquery with ajax.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=txt_search_extantdata.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
                url: "/_layouts/Extantlibrarywebservice/getdata.asmx/GetSearchData",
                data: { 'src': $("#<%=txt_search_extantdata.ClientID%>").val() },

                                    dataType: "xml",
                                    success: function (xmlResponse) {
                                        response($(xmlResponse).map(function () {
                                            return { value: $(this).text() };
                                        }))
                                    },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }

            });

        },
        minLength: 2

    });
});
```

what i am gettting output currently is like this 
one single item with all strings attached

```
          Air PollutantsAir FacilitiesAir EmissionsAir Pollution Air Quality MonitoringAir Piracy
```

what i want to display in out put is one string in one line

```
       Air Pollutants
       AirFacilities
       Air Emissions
       Air Pollution
       Air Quality Monitoring
       Air Piracy
```

I am not able to figure out what i am doing wrong any help please...

Comment: have you looked at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#xml and http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/xml.html

Comment: check your web service returning xml or not in network panel of firebug/chrome console/ie devtools

Comment: it returns xml the structure above is copied from the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok figured it out , your success callback should be like this :

```
  success: function (xmlResponse) {
                        response($("string", xmlResponse).map(function () {
                            return {
                                value: $(this).text()
                            };
                        }));
                    },
```

because here you are getting response which contains xml node of string inside ArrayofStrings
your selector to map inside response should be like this

```
$("string", xmlResponse)
```

hope that helps !!